# .Net Core 3.0 With AWS ECS(docker run -m)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0

docker run -m

How do I write to the AWS ECS Task File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally such question is strongly discouraged, you should show what you have done and what the problem you are facing. but here is a step.

- Better to push your image to [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/)
- Specify an image ARN in the [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html)
- Create [service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ecs_services.html) from the task definition

```
{
   "containerDefinitions": [ 
      { 

         "entryPoint": [
            "sh",
            "-c"
         ],
         "essential": true,
         "image": "PUT_RESGISTRY_ECR_IMAGE_ARN_HERE",
         "logConfiguration": { 
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": { 
               "awslogs-group" : "/ecs/fargate-task-definition",
               "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
               "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
            }
         },
         "name": "sample-fargate-app",
         "portMappings": [ 
            { 
               "containerPort": 80,
               "hostPort": 80,
               "protocol": "tcp"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "cpu": "256",
   "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::012345678910:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
   "family": "fargate-task-definition",
   "memory": "512",
   "networkMode": "awsvpc",
   "requiresCompatibilities": [ 
       "FARGATE" 
    ]
}
```

[example_task_definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/example_task_definitions.html)

[getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-docker-containers/)

[deploying-a-simple-hello-world-httpd-container-on-an-ecs-cluster](https://medium.com/@mohitshrestha02/deploying-a-simple-hello-world-httpd-container-on-an-ecs-cluster-64c880d265f0)